# Photo blurry when loaded i application

Tags: android, save, photo, blurry

I have implemented this photo taking style.  When I preview the photo after I take it,
it is beautiful, but when I reload it in the app it looks blurry.  Here is the code, 
does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

```
private void takePhoto(int actionCode) 
    {
        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        newImageP = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        newImage.setImageBitmap(newImageP);     
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that the Camera activity sends back a thumbnail of the image. If this low quality image gets upscaled, you will see it blurry.

To get the full resolution image you should call the camera activity with the following extra

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(   temporalPictureFile ) );
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, actionCode);
```

This is so the camera app can dump the content of the image to a physical file and don't mess with the app memory being very limited.
As far as i remember, the file has to exists before passing it in the intent.

Comment: What do I put for the "temporalPictureFile"??

Comment: It should be the path of the file where you want the image to be saved

Comment: What would the path be though?

Comment: It would be a the path to where you want the file to be stored. Example: /sdcard/MyAwesomeApp/pictures/Image11-11-2012.png

Comment: Can you store it on the built in memory?

Comment: No. that's exactly the point. A big picture might cause memory problems to your application.